# How to specify which child taks to run on watch grunt config

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-watch

I have the following watch configuration that reloads the page and run others tasks.

```
watch: {
            js: {
                files: ['gruntfile.js', 'server.js', 'app/**/*.js', 'public/js/**', 'test/**/*.js'],
                tasks: ['jshint'],
                options: {
                    livereload: true,
                },
            },
            html: {
                files: ['public/views/**', 'app/views/**'],
                options: {
                    livereload: true,
                },
            },
            css: {
                files: ['public/css/**'],
                options: {
                    livereload: true
                }
            },
            test: {
                files: ['app/**/*.js', 'test/mocha/**/*.js'],
                tasks: ['mochaTest', 'karma:unit']
            }
        },
```

I don't want to run the "test" option inside watch task, I just want to run it when I specify that, like in my test task:

```
grunt.registerTask('test-w', ['mochaTest', 'karma:unit', 'watch:test']);
```

I've tried to do this inside concurrent task:

```
tasks: ['nodemon', 'watch:js:html:css']
```

Didn't work unfortunetly :(

Comment: Just take `test` out of your `watch` block. Can you show your whole gruntfile? This problem sounds weird.

Comment: Here you are
https://gist.github.com/DanilloCorvalan/9140163

Comment: It's not weird at all, I totally get it. Unfortunately, I don't know the solution except leaving `app/**/*.js` out of your `watch:test` task.

Comment: If there was a way to specify which commands you want to run :(
As I'm doing tdd I'd like to have a watch for running my tests on every change I do. But I don't want it to run the tests when I'm running my app in browser for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just specify all necessary watch tasks in `concurrent`:

```
tasks : ['nodemon', 'watch:js', 'watch:html', 'watch:css']
```

Comment: I had tried that before but it complained that port 35729 was already being used by 'watch:js'. I realised that this was because every config (js, html and css) was set with livereload:true. I sorted it out by making a single config (all) that watches everything instead of having it separated. Thanks!